# How to get Codename One Form feature vertical scroll?

Tags: codenameone

My Codename One app features a Form with 3 SpanLabels containing text and one Container in LayeredLayout with an image and an overlay.

```
    this.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, spanLab1);
    this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, imageCont);
    this.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, BoxLayout.encloseY(spanLab2, spanLabl3));
```

This yields to the following:

[image: Form not scrollable (text is irrelevant)]

This is not satisfactory as the image (that appears in the center and should be CN1 icon) is not scaled but cut because it is not possible to scroll down.

I tried to force the Form to be scrollable (`this.setScrollableY(true)`) without success.

Did I make a mistake somewhere, <strike>for example should all my content be placed in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` since according to the [documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html) the NORTH position is dedicated for the title and the SOUTH one for an optional menu bar (I tried this without success)</strike>?

Or should I show a Dialog instead (that offers Y-Scroll out of the box) ? What is actually the proper way to show all my (long) content with no picture cut or text overlaping ?

**EDIT December 22nd 2016**

As @Tizbn wrote the Form's ContentPane has to be in Vertical BoxLayout. So the call to the parent constructor has to be written :

`super(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical Scroll is disable in BorderLayout . For that BoxLayout with Y-axis can be used and make setScrollableY(true) in the Boxlayout. Hope it will help .

Comment: I would add that border layout gives north/south/east/west the preferred size on the opposing axis. It gives center the reminder. Usually you don't want stuff that grows (e.g. large blocks of text) in the sides of the border layout.

Comment: Perfect this was the way to go, thanks @Tizbn! @Shai I mistakenly understandood the [doc]( https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html) since `this.add(Component)` <=> `this.getContentPane().add()` so my antepenultimate paragraph is all wrong!